# IBM Watson unable to authenticate to the API

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

not using curl
But following a node.js tutorial to build a sentiment analysis app for slack using IBM Watson tone analyzer. My process.env has already credentials from IBM like with the London instance url:

```
TONE_ANALYZER_IAM_APIKEY=<MY API KEY>
TONE_ANALYZER_URL=https://api.eu-gb.tone-analyzer.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/c2f8238d- 
cf7a-4184-9bc2-315e0a204d3a
```

The index.js

```
const ToneAnalyzerV3 = require('watson-developer-cloud/tone-analyzer/v3');
const toneAnalyzer = new ToneAnalyzerV3({
  iam_apikey: process.env.TONE_ANALYZER_IAM_APIKEY,
  url: 'https://api.eu-gb.tone-analyzer.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/c2f8238d-cf7a-4184- 
  9bc2-315e0a204d3a',
version: '2017-09-21',
```

I'm getting this error still

```
Error: Insufficient credentials provided in constructor argument. Refer to the documentation 
for the required parameters. Common examples are username/password and iam_access_token.
at ToneAnalyzerV3.BaseService.initCredentials (/Users/qtn3118/sentimentapp/node_modules/ibm- 
cloud-sdk-core/lib/base_service.js:243:23)
at ToneAnalyzerV3.BaseService (/Users/qtn3118/sentimentapp/node_modules/ibm-cloud-sdk-core/lib/base_service.js:98:29)
at ToneAnalyzerV3 [as constructor] (/Users/qtn3118/sentimentapp/node_modules/watson-developer-cloud/tone-analyzer/v3-generated.js:57:28)
at new ToneAnalyzerV3 (/Users/qtn3118/sentimentapp/node_modules/watson-developer-cloud/tone-analyzer/v3.js:34:23)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/qtn3118/sentimentapp/index.js:38:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
```

I tried with both API keys from "Manage" and "Service credentials" tabs from the IBM Watson dashboard - none of them work. Any one any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this way

[Watson APIs Node.js SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm-watson)

```
import AssistantV1 from 'ibm-watson/assistant/v1';
import { IamAuthenticator } from 'ibm-watson/auth';

export const createAssistant = configs => new AssistantV1({
  authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({ apikey: configs.apiKey }),
  url: configs.url,
  version: '2019-02-28'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

More information about authentication is available in the SDK reference at https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/tone-analyzer?code=node#authentication